# Is it possible to specify an uri in Nginx proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have a question, is it possible to specify a URI in the Nginx proxy_pass directive?

I currently host two websites on my windows server on a lan network that are set up and accessible via nginx. But I have one problem. One of these sites, which is hosted at my home, needs to specify a uri, because it is not possible to reach it via the normal ip address that I have set in nginx.

To be specific, a subdomain "emfavm.emfasandbox.tk" is reverse proxyed to lan ip "192.168.1.106" by using proxy_pass. I can get to this page using this ip address, but I need to specify the uri, something like this: "https://192.168.1.106/some/uri". I host these pages on another virtual server. When I put this uri as above in proxy_pass in nginx.conf, and I connect to the domain "emfavm.emfasandbox.tk", it gives me an error "bad request, your browser sent a request that this server could not understand"

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
server_names_hash_bucket_size  64;
    include       mime.types; 
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
#=============== HERE IS THE CONF WITH THE HOSTED WEBISTES ======================
    include       C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*.conf;    
#================================================================================



    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

And this is the conf with the website in C:/nginx/sites-enabled/emfavm.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name emfavm.emfasandbox.tk;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://192.168.1.106/#/?username=www.emfasandbox.tk&password=emfasandbox/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to change `https` to `http` in C:/nginx/sites-enabled/emfavm.conf